# Clinking link do not trigger Servlet no response from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a page called:
 `functionNamesRegister.jsp`

and servlet called 
`functionNamesRegisterServlet`

functionNamesRegister is accessed by clicking on that link:

```
<li><a href='functionNamesRegister.jsp' class='daddy'>Register FM Function Names</a></li> <br>
```

Then in the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    request.setAttribute("test", "TEST TEST TEST TEST");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("functionNamesRegister.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

And Then in jsp I want to display that test by just doing that: `${test}`
But it does not work. Other servlet are working when I use them for example in forms like:

```
<form name='myForm' action='componentRegisterServlet' method='post' onSubmit='return validateCrForm()'>
```

Why is that do I do wrong?

Comment: Try removing the ".jsp" from the HTML link?

Comment: OMG that really works... I did it previously but I do not know why it did not work...
Thank you kind sir

Comment: Can you explain me why is that? I presume that when I do it with .jsp then there is no way fot servlet to execute?

Comment: Because the servlet is apparently mapped with that name - I assume that you configured it that way....

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are meant to be the target of your links, then they redirect to a jsp page as needed.

Servlet url patterns are defined in configuration files (usually web.xml), so thay can be something like:

- /functionNamesRegister
- /functionNamesRegister.do
- /action/functionNamesRegister

If you link directly to the jsp page (View layer) you are bypassing all Servlet code (Controller layer), and propably jsp page has no parameters enough to render properly, not to mention de lack of all actions executed in the servlet.